# Technique for dealing with nils in a deeply nested object model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a legacy rails application that has deeply nested associations.  I have requirements that call for some of the deeply nested attributes to be bubbled up and displayed.

At the moment I am doing something like this to display results (using ActiveRecord Associations and Arrays)

```
model_a
  .collection_of_model_b
  .map(&:collection_model_c)
  .flatten
  .map(&:collection_model_d)
  .display_field
```

This approach worked with test data but once I started using real data I started noticing NilClass errors all over the place.

Please provide guidance in terms of technique, syntax, patterns that I can use to fetch this data.

Some approaches that I have thought about but have not pursued yet:
1) Break up the calls in separate lines doing a check for nils each time I go down a level.
2) Use straight sql ( find_by_sql ).

Comment: `.reject` to filter out nil values maybe?

Comment: which step introduces nil objects?

Comment: Step changes based on which model_a I pick.  Sometimes it is a a model_b object that comes up nil in the Array, Other times it is model_c or model_d. As mentioned below I am going to try to run compact before calling map in every case to protect against nils.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Array#compact](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000278):

```
>> [1, 2, nil, 3].compact
=> [1, 2, 3]

>> [[1, 2], [3, nil], [4]].map(&:compact)
=> [[1, 2], [3], [4]]
```

Comment: Yes, I am going to run that before each call to an association.  If you have any other suggestions please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any has_may :through associations? like

```
class ModelA < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :model_bs
  has_many :model_cs, :through => :model_bs
  has_many :model_ds, :through => :model_cs
  ...
end
```

Personally, I think this still violates the Law of Demeter, as ModelA still knows a lot about the members of models B & C.  But this at least abstracts it away and now you can just call:

```
model_a.model_ds.map(&:display_field)
```